# Export a specific older version of AWS Lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda which has 3 Alias.

1. ALIAS DEV: Linked to my DEVELOPMENT STAGE pointing to $LATEST version
2. ALIAS SBX: Linked to my SBX/QA STAGE pointing to Lambda Version #2
3. ALIAS PRD: Linked to my PRODUCTION STAGE pointing to Lambda Version #1 [Most stable version]

Now i am trying to export the Version #1 or #2 via the AWS console. When i try to export the function i only get the $LATEST.

Is there a way to Export an earlier Lambda version?

[Note: the lambda is built on C# so viewing in the AWS console is not an option.]

Comment: You need to visit the lambda version page first before you click export.

Comment: I do that but still get the $Latest version.

Comment: It could be that the version you are trying to export contains the same code as the $Latest. I tried it on my lambda function, and it exported the version correctly.

Comment: @jellycsc Is your lambda function a c# .net package?

Comment: No, but it shouldn't matter. Are you 100% confident that two versions are running different code?

Comment: yup thats correct. I am 100% confident.